# Compare current password of a Linux user with an entered password in Perl

Tags: linux, unix, encryption, passwords, perl

I would like to get to know if the password a username has provided in a form is the one that user has on the system in a given host... I need this in order to change the password or return an error message to the user who requested it. Specifically would like it done in Perl.

i have the following test to see if user exists the if successful do the passwords matching and the if success do the change to the new password provided with the request I'm using JSON Rpc Dispatcher to serve the client.

```
if (getpwnam("$username")) { 
#  if ($currentpass == $sytempass)  {}              
return "User $username password is $newpass success!";
#   else { return current password is incorrect}       
} 
else {
return "user $username never existed here";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Linux authentication interface is PAM, e.g. [Authen::PAM](http://search.cpan.org/~nikip/Authen-PAM-0.16/d/PAM.pm) or [Authen::Simple::PAM](http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Authen-Simple-PAM-0.2/lib/Authen/Simple/PAM.pm). For example:

```
use Authen::Simple::PAM;

my $pam = Authen::Simple::PAM->new(service => "login");

if ($pam->authenticate($username, $password)) {
    # ...
}
```

For *local accounts* only, the password hashes are usually stored in the "shadow" file. Perl will automatically retrieve them when calling `getpwent()`:

```
my @pwent = getpwnam($username);
my $known_good_hash = $pwent[1];
my $checking_hash = crypt($password, $known_good_hash);

if ($checking_hash eq $known_good_hash) {
    # ...
}
```

(The `crypt()` function takes a "salt" as the second argument. When comparing against a hash, you should give it the full original hash, and it'll extract the salt from it.)

Note that you **must have root access** to use either facility.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. I had not realized you could obtain the salt from the digest itself! I was about to write: you cannot do this because the two salts are not the same... LOL, you taught me something and spared me an embarrassment, thanks.

Comment: The second option using getpwent() is perfect just tested it and it's awesome thanks Grawity!!!

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Yes, crypt() hashes are in the form of `$alg$salt$hash` for most modern algorithms, or `ssHHHHHHHHHHH` for old DES hashes, containing the salt in both cases. _It's how the OS itself verifies passwords against /etc/shadow, too._